# Looking for a synonym for Block

Tags: synonyms

I need to find some synonym for block or some other word to say that some thing is not happening but I need that word to start with U. I want to express that a protein is blocking a cellular process.

I can't find it, is there any?

Comment: This is a page where all the synonyms of block might be http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/block, of course, without more context, this might be all you can find

Comment: Why is it necessary to start with a `u`?

Comment: I want to express that a protein is blocking a cellular process. In concret that some cells do not enter apoptosis, so they do not die when they are supposed to.

Comment: The U stuff is to make a joke with the title of the presentation.

Comment: If you gave us the whole title, we might have some chance of finding a word.

Comment: P35 (which is the name of the mutant), an apoptotoc "blocker"

Comment: P35, [process] unavailable/unachievable/'unpossible'?

Comment: You really need to explain what part of speech you want. A verb?

Comment: The synonym list yields "upset".

Comment: (But, as you have neither shown us the research you've done nor provided sufficient context for the word you're seeking, this question should be closed.)

Answer (score 1):

*Untenable*, not capable of being maintained or defended (American Heritage)

---

**Edit:** If you want a verb or a past participle:

*unactivate*

*unactivated*

Answer (score 0):

What about unable? The cellular process is unable to occur due to the protein's presence.

Comment: The problem is that it should be the last word. It would be something like [mutant name], [process] blocked. But thank you :)